# Spring ehcache - #root.targetClass value if return type is List<User>?

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I have the following method:

```
@Cacheable(value="settings", key = "#root.targetClass")
@Override   
public List<MySeeting> getAll() {
    return Lists.newArrayList(settingRepository.findAll());
}
```

What's the value from #root.targetClass?
List< MySeeting > or MySeeting?

I'm using Spring 4 and the ehcache.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-spel-context) `targetClass` is the class of the target being invoked, that is the type of the object on which the method is invoked. So it has nothing to do with the return type of the method.

In any case, because of generics erasure in Java, having access to the return type would only give you the type `List`.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer I was looking for, I found this code googling:

```
public void getCache() {
    Object nativeCache = cacheManager.getCache("mycache").getNativeCache();

    if (nativeCache instanceof net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache) {
        net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache ehCache = (net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache) nativeCache;
        ehCache.getKeys();
      }
}
```

By inspecting "ehCache.getKeys()" I could see that "#root.targetClass" is actually "class com.test.service.impl.MyService" (MyService class is where the getAll method mentioned above is declared)